# Access violation at address

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-7

> Access violation at address 004295A6 in module 'frameprj.exe'. Read of address 6432FF68.

I Use Delphi2007 and I want to build an app which contains a form, a advtoolbar, advofficepager and a mainmenu. Based on what button from MainMenu I Click a different Menu should load on the AdvToolBar and a page should be created if it doesn't exists or should be set as active page if it exists. The problem is after creating the pages when I click on a MainManu item again I get this error, and It looks like i get it because of the `AdvToolBar.Menu := Menu;` line of code.

Here is the code.

```
unit framepage;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, frameFunctii, framePersone, AdvOfficePager,
  Menus, AdvToolBar;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    AdvOfficePager1 : TAdvOfficePager;
    MainMenu1 : TMainMenu;
    Personal1 : TMenuItem;
    Functii1 : TMenuItem;
    Exit1 : TMenuItem;
    Adaugare1 : TMenuItem;
    Inspectare1 : TMenuItem;
    AdvToolBar1 : TAdvToolBar;

    procedure Exit1Click( Sender : TObject );
    procedure Personal1Click( Sender : TObject );
    procedure Inspectare1Click( Sender : TObject );
    procedure Adaugare1Click( Sender : TObject );
    procedure AdvOfficePager1ClosedPage( Sender : TObject; PageIndex : Integer );
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  DataModule, frameAdaugareFunctie;

procedure TForm1.Personal1Click( Sender : TObject );

var
  fp : TFrame2;
  AdvOfficePager11 : TAdvOfficePage;
  i : Integer;
  gasit : boolean;
begin
  gasit := False;
  AdvToolBar1.Menu := nil;
  for i := 0 to AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount - 1 do
    begin
      if AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i].Caption = 'Personal'
      then
        begin
          AdvOfficePager11 := AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i];
          AdvToolBar1.Menu := fp.MainMenu1;
          gasit := True;
        end;
    end;
  if not gasit
  then
    begin
      AdvOfficePager11 := TAdvOfficePage.Create( AdvOfficePager1 );
      AdvOfficePager11.Caption := 'Personal';
      fp := TFrame2.Create( AdvOfficePager11 );
      fp.Parent := AdvOfficePager11;
      fp.Align := alClient;
      AdvOfficePager11.ShowClose := True;
      AdvOfficePager1.AddAdvPage( AdvOfficePager11 );
      AdvOfficePager1.ButtonSettings.CloseButton := True;
      AdvToolBar1.Menu := fp.MainMenu1;
    end;

  AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage := AdvOfficePager11;

end;

procedure TForm1.Adaugare1Click( Sender : TObject );

var
  frmAdgFct : TframeAdgFunctie;
  AdvOfficePager13 : TAdvOfficePage;
  i : Integer;
  gasit : boolean;
begin
  gasit := False;
  for i := 0 to AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount - 1 do
    begin
      if AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i].Caption = 'Adaugare functie'
      then
        begin
          AdvOfficePager13 := AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i];
          gasit := True;
        end;
    end;
  if not gasit
  then
    begin
      AdvOfficePager13 := TAdvOfficePage.Create( AdvOfficePager1 );
      AdvOfficePager13.Caption := 'Adaugare functie';
      frmAdgFct := TframeAdgFunctie.Create( AdvOfficePager13 );
      frmAdgFct.Parent := AdvOfficePager13;
      frmAdgFct.Align := alClient;
      AdvOfficePager13.ShowClose := True;
      AdvOfficePager1.AddAdvPage( AdvOfficePager13 );
      AdvOfficePager1.ButtonSettings.CloseButton := True;
    end;
  AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage := AdvOfficePager13;

end;

procedure TForm1.AdvOfficePager1ClosedPage( Sender : TObject; PageIndex : Integer );
begin
  AdvToolBar1.Menu := nil;
end;

procedure TForm1.Exit1Click( Sender : TObject );
begin
  DataModule1.Free;
  Form1.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Inspectare1Click( Sender : TObject );
var
  ff : TFrame1;
  AdvOfficePager12 : TAdvOfficePage;
  i : Integer;
  gasit : boolean;
begin
  AdvToolBar1.Menu := nil;
  gasit := False;
  for i := 0 to AdvOfficePager1.AdvPageCount - 1 do
    begin
      if AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i].Caption = 'Functii'
      then
        begin
          AdvOfficePager12 := AdvOfficePager1.AdvPages[i];
          AdvToolBar1.Menu := ff.MainMenu1;
          gasit := True;
        end;
    end;
  if not gasit
  then
    begin
      AdvOfficePager12 := TAdvOfficePage.Create( AdvOfficePager1 );
      AdvOfficePager12.Caption := 'Functii';
      ff := TFrame1.Create( AdvOfficePager12 );
      ff.Parent := AdvOfficePager12;
      ff.Align := alClient;
      AdvOfficePager12.ShowClose := True;
      AdvOfficePager1.AddAdvPage( AdvOfficePager12 );
      AdvOfficePager1.ButtonSettings.CloseButton := True;
      AdvToolBar1.Menu := ff.MainMenu1;
    end;

  AdvOfficePager1.ActivePage := AdvOfficePager12;

end;

end.
```

Comment: Your next step is to do some debugging. Run under the debugger and let it break at the AV. Look at the line of code that fails and work out which pointer is invalid.

Comment: I know where it breaks, it breaks at AdvToolBar1.Menu := fp.MainMenu1; and  AdvToolBar1.Menu := ff.MainMenu1; in the for statement, the problem is I have no idea why.

Comment: This question basically is not useful to anyone else because it's a "here is my code, I have no idea how anything works in pascal, or what an object type variable reference is, or what a nil pointer and an uninitialized variable reference is" question. I think you can do better, right?

Comment: I don't think it should be usefull to everyone, that's the point of this site, so you, he or me to post our own code problems so that we understand where we were mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this line

```
AdvToolBar1.Menu := fp.MainMenu1;
```

in `TForm1.Personal1Click`, the variable `fp` has not been initialised.

Furthermore, at this line

```
AdvToolBar1.Menu := ff.MainMenu1;
```

in `TForm1.Inspectare1Click`, the variable `ff` has not been initialised.

You must initialise variables before you attempt to use them.

Comment: It depends. It's your program. What do you intend the code to do? I note that you do initialise these variables later in the functions.

Comment: But shouldn't those Frames be initialised from the creation of the page from the AdvOfficePager, becouse  "AdvToolBar1.Menu := ff.MainMenu1;" executes only if the page already exists so if the page exists so should the fp and ff Frames.

Comment: @ David Heffernan, I try to dynamically create Pages and Frames into a form and add to each Page a frame.

Comment: I managed to solve my error, I declared the fp : TFrame2;
  ff : TFrame1; as global variables and now it works. Still I can't figure out how to dynamically change the menu when the activepage is modified.  Edit : I marked your answer as accepted answer as your idea made me solve the error. Thank you

Comment: @CiucaS Please undo your edit to the question. Now my answer no longer matches your question. Please return the code in the question to its original state. As for using global variables that is absolutely the wrong solution. You should make these variables be fields of the class. Even then I cannot tell whether or not that is enough to make your program do what you intend. Fundamentally though, the question was about the AVs and that's what I addressed. How you solve the problem is really down to you.